# CAShapeLayer animation doesn't fire animationDidStop

Tags: swift, animation, core-animation, tvos

Running tvOS using Swift 3.0

Basic app, this is the code in the view controller... I want to remove the `CAShapeLayer` after it has faded out. The animation works perfectly, but the completion method `animationDidStop` never gets called?

Want to use `override func animationDidStop` method, but it won't compile. Gives me the error "method does not override any method from its superclass" which is wrong surely, `animationDidStop` is a member of `CAAnimation` class.

What is wrong with this code? I could fix this with a timer or something I guess, but it a fudge.

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore


class ViewController: UIViewController, CALayerDelegate, CAAnimationDelegate {

var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    highlight(XCord: 100, YCord: 100)
    clearhighlight()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func highlight(XCord: CGFloat, YCord: CGFloat) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: XCord,y: YCord), radius: CGFloat(20), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

        self.shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

        //change the fill color
        //shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.shapeLayer.opacity = 0.5
        self.shapeLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

        //you can change the stroke color
        self.shapeLayer.strokeColor =  UIColor.red.cgColor
        //you can change the line width
        self.shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.shapeLayer)
        }
    }
}

func clearhighlight() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let fadeInAndOut = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        fadeInAndOut.duration = 10.0;
        //fadeInAndOut.autoreverses = true;
        fadeInAndOut.repeatCount = 1
        fadeInAndOut.fromValue = 1.0
        fadeInAndOut.toValue = 0.0
        fadeInAndOut.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
        fadeInAndOut.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        //self.view.layer.delegate = self
        self.shapeLayer.delegate = self
        self.shapeLayer.add(fadeInAndOut, forKey: "fadeOut")
        self.shapeLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    print("animationDidStop")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.shapeLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}



}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the delegate of the shape layer:

```
self.shapeLayer.delegate = self
```

But if you wanted `animationDidStop` to be called, you have to set the `delegate` of the animation, not of the layer:

```
fadeInAndOut.delegate = self
```

---

You say:

> Want to use `override func animationDidStop` method, but it won't compile. Gives me the error "method does not override any method from its superclass" which is wrong surely, `animationDidStop` is a member of `CAAnimation` class.

You are implementing this in your view controller and `UIViewController` does not provide a base class implementation of `animationDidStop`, so there is nothing to override.

The `animationDidStop` is a method defined by the `CAAnimationDelegate` protocol, so (a) the view controller should declare its conformance to that protocol; and (b) do not use the `override`  keyword.